# Android Image Gallery Slide Between Images

Tags: java, android, android-glide

I used this guide https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/code-an-image-gallery-android-app-with-glide--cms-28207 to add an image gallery on my app. It works perfect but I want when the user clicks on an image and display it to be able to see the other images by sliding left or right. Any ideas???

Comment: you can use ViewPager with pagerAdapter to create a slidshow of your images.

Comment: This was the first thing i tried but can't make it work. If you could show me a code example i would be grateful.

Comment: http://codetheory.in/android-image-slideshow-using-viewpager-pageradapter/ this link seems relevant. though it uses static image resources, but you can change the code to use your bitmap instead. If you are still stuck, share specific problem here. someone will surely help you out.

Comment: Yes i think this will work. I'll give it a try and let you know. Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 0):

Use `ViewPager` to create slide show of images. 
There are so many libs with same functionality you can refer them here :

1) [GestureViews](https://github.com/alexvasilkov/GestureViews)
2) [ImagePicker](https://github.com/martin90s/ImagePicker)